# Multiple value with same key in Route

Tags: c#, servicestack

Do I have this possibility to have multiple value in query string and map it into a property? same as example at below:

GET http://site/api/v1/test?Id=10&Id=11&Id=12

```
[Route("/api/v1/test")]
public class TestRequest {
   public int[] Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 1. Well route or query? 2. RouteAttribute can be used on controller class but TestRequest seems not to be a controller. - Please take your time and reword your question

Comment: @sir-rufo please look at the tags. my question is related to the ServiceStack ( http://docs.servicestack.net/routing ) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send multiple values and [complex types using the JSV Format](http://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#passing-complex-objects-in-the-query-string), e.g:

```
/api/v1/test?id=10,11,12
```

Comment: that was requested by customer, i'll ask them to change it in this way